# Android: Copy to clipboard selected text from a TextView

Tags: android, copy, textview, clipboard

Is there a possibility to copy to clipboard from a TextView UI component only the selected text?

I've catched the long press event and I copied the full text to clipboard, but now I want to specify the start and the end of the selection to be copied from a TextView.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can use a EditText instead of TextView, you could possibly achieve this.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
TextView tv;
String stringYouExtracted = tv.getText().toString();
int startIndex = tv.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = tv.getSelectionEnd();
stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.subString(startIndex, endIndex);
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
```

---

**EDIT *(The previous is the full answer, but I ran into my answer by mistake so I would like to add)***:

With Newer APIs, change the last two lines to :

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
} else {
    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", stringYouExtracted);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

`"Copied Text"` is a title for your COPY entity in newer APIS

Comment: But how can be specified the start index and the end index by long pressing the textview?

Comment: @ASP it should work on all devices but I really haven't tested it 100%. plz do tell us if it doesn't work

Comment: @SherifelKhatib but android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB is not working on below versions. Any way 'else' part work for me perfectly. Thanks 4 dat

Comment: How would you run the "else" part from command line, using something like: `service call clipboard 2 i32 1 i32 0 s16 "Hi there"`?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
ClipboardManager myClipboard = myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData myClip;
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
int min = 0;
int max = editText.getText().length();
if (editText.isFocused()) {
    final int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
    final int selEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
    max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));
}
// here is your selected text
final CharSequence selectedText = editText.getText().subSequence(min, max);
String text = selectedText.toString();


// copy to clipboard
myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
```

Replace EditText with TextView