# select & copy to clipboard in TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, clipboard

Is it possible to allow the user to select and then copy text in the clipboard in a TextView?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview) but there isn't an answer.

I have also tried to set `android:textIsSelectable="true"` but it didn't work.

Comment: see this post maybe helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624763/android-copy-to-clipboard-selected-text-from-a-textview

Comment: Thanks, that will help but it isn't the answer. It will work when the user will be able to select a text.

Comment: use EditText instead of TextView and make it not editable?

Comment: It has several problems. 1) it shows useless things like the marks for wrongly spelled words, 2) on some devices if you allow the focus to be acquired it does weird things like allowing you to paste in the edittext even is it is not editable 3) if you disallow the focus the selection is not possible anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using an EditText but to avoid the problems I described in my answer to "imran khan" I found a comment about setKeyListener in the android code:

> ```
>  * Be warned that if you want a TextView with a key listener or movement
>  * method not to be focusable, or if you want a TextView without a
>  * key listener or movement method to be focusable, you must call
>  * {@link #setFocusable} again after calling this to get the focusability
>  * back the way you want it.
> ```

So the problem is that when you set the flag editable to false setKeyListener is called and the focusable flag is overwritten.

To fix it, in the onCreate of my activity I added:

```
    tesxtView.setKeyListener(null);
    tesxtView.setFocusable(true);
```

By doing this I also got rid of the marks for the wrongly spelled words

Comment: Wait, so it is possible to use a TextView with the text-selection (with copying it) or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think that starting with Lollipop, this actually works as you'd expect it (tested on [**my app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager), after I've changed a few things) :

[image]

I used [**this library**](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro), and changed this attribute for the file "adp_alert_dialog_material.xml", to just have the attribute you've asked about (on a TextView) :

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```