# how to change a text of selected EditText (android)

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext

I have 2 EditText and a button. When I click the button I want to print a text in the editText which is selected.. How I can do this??

Comment: see following post [Android: Copy to clipboard selected text from a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624763/android-copy-to-clipboard-selected-text-from-a-textview)

Comment: I have anything to do with this post... I only want to know how to distinguish
the selected editText (where tHere is the cursor) and the other ediText.. because I want firstly to set the text in editText 1 and then, with the same button, set the text in editText 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

[Get Cursor Position in Android in Edit Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900408/get-cursor-position-in-android-in-edit-text)

In your onClick ask for the myEditText.getSelectionStart(); if is not null thats your EditText.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

It looks more complicated than i thought at first, you are looking for a focus state. See if any of this answers helps you.

[How can I detect focused EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341946/how-can-i-detect-focused-edittext-in-android)